# How to use Flutter State Restoration with HookWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks, flutter-state-restoration

I want to use Flutter State Restoration in my Flutter app. I want to save/restore some data and on internet all articles suggest to use `RestorationMixin` for this. How can I use `RestorationMixin` with `HookWidget` ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have the answer now, it can be done using **RestorationBucket** directly. Below is the complete source code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      restorationScopeId: 'root',
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends HookWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  static const counterKey = 'counter-key';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final refreshCounter = useState(0);
    final restorationBucket = RestorationScope.of(context);
    final counter = restorationBucket?.read<int>(counterKey) ?? 0;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Restore State Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          restorationBucket?.write(counterKey, counter + 1);
          refreshCounter.value++;
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

We can also use this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod_restorable) but I am not sure if it will be maintained regularly.

Comment: In case if MaterialApp needs a restored data, we can wrap the MaterialApp with RootRestorationScope and set restorationId there instead of MaterialApp's restorationScopeId.